ARC and the release of custom objects passed into async network methods
In my app I’m running into a problem leaking custom objects passed into a chain of methods that store HTML files into a custom object. Where each method finds a local copy of a file, the file is read in and referenced by an NSString in the custom object. When no local copy of the file exists, the method makes an asynchronous network request with the completion routine saving the contents locally and again storing a reference to the data read in the custom object.
Things work fine as long as I have local copies of each file: the HTML is read from the local file, the reference is stored in the custom object, and the next method in the chain is called. There are about 2 dozen methods in the chain, and once done the HTML files are processed, I set the reference to the custom object to nil, and repeat the whole process with a different set of 24 HTML files. As long as everything is local, an examination of the memory map shows that no objects have leaked.
Problems begin, however, when any one of the HTML files is not available locally and that file is fetched from the web. In those cases, the custom object used to store references to the data is never released via ARC.
My code (here, a mix of real and pseudo code) looks like this:
@interface CustomObject : NSObject
@property   (strong)    NSString              *htmlPage1;
@property   (strong)    NSString              *htmlPage2;
@property   (strong)    NSString              *htmlPage3;
@property   (strong)    NSMutableArray        *array;
@property   (strong)    DifferentCustomObject *c1;
@end

The custom object is then created within a loop, like so:
- (void) loop: (int) n {
    CustomObject    *co;
    int         i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        co  = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
        co.c1 = [[DifferentCustomObject alloc] init];
        [self startFileFetchChain: co];
    }
}

And the custom object is set to nil once the request chain has ended.
- (void) endFileFetchChain: (CustomObject *) co {
    if (co.array)
        [co.array removeAllObjects];
    if (co.c1)
        co.c1 = nil;
    co = nil;
}

This is the beginning of the chain of methods that will (hopefully) fetch 24 HTML files.
- (void) startFileFetchChain: (CustomObject *) co {
     __block NSURLSessionTask    *task = nil;
             NSURL               *pageURL;
    // Check to see if we have a local copy of the file, which gets stored in localPageSource
    if (localPageSource) {
        // Store a reference to read data in the custom object
        co.htmlPage1 = localPageSource;
        // Call the next method in the chain
        [self requestNextPageInTheChain: co];
    }
    else {
        // Create the URL for this page page, which we put in pageURL
        task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:pageURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        switch ([httpResponse statusCode]) {
            case 200:
                // Store the HTML page into the custom object
                co.htmlPage1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                // Save this file locally so we won’t have to make a network request next time
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    // File system code here; missing for brevity
                    [co.htmlPage1 writeToFile: localPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                    // Call the next method in the chain
                    [self requestNextPageInTheChain: co];
                });
                break;
            default:
                // Error case. The chain is severed before running to completion
                [self endFileFetchChain: co];
                break;
        }
        }];
        [task resume];
    }
}

The chain continues here.
- (void) requestNextPageInTheChain: (CustomObject *) co {
    // Basically, a repeat of the above, but storing the local or network fetched HTML page into co.htmlPage2
    // and then chaining to a subsequent method to request the next HTML page.
    // This repeats for all 24 HTML pages until we reach the final page, which is in the next method.
 }

- (void) requestLastPageInTheChain: (CustomObject *) co {
     __block NSURLSessionTask    *task = nil;
             NSURL               *pageURL;
    // Check to see if we have a local copy of the file, which gets stored in localPageSource
    if (localPageSource) {
        // Store a reference to read data in the custom object
        co.htmlPage1 = localPageSource;
        // Call the next method in the chain
        [self processAllThePages: co];          // <— We’re now done with all the requests
    }
    else {
        // Create the URL for this page page, which we put in pageURL
        task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:pageURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        switch ([httpResponse statusCode]) {
            case 200:
                // Store the HTML page into the custom object
                co.htmlPage1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                // Save this file locally so we won’t have to make a network request next time
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                    // File system code here; missing for brevity
                    [co.htmlPage1 writeToFile: localPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
                    // Call the next method in the chain
                    [self processAllThePages: co];          // <— We’re now done with all the requests
                });
                break;
            default:
                // Error case. The chain is severed before running to completion
                [self endFileFetchChain: co];
                break;
        }
        }];
        [task resume];
    }
 }

And the chain concludes with this method.
- (void) processAllThePages: (CustomObject *) co {
    // Do a bunch of stuff with the 24 HTML pages 
    [self endFileFetchChain: co];
}

Okay, when all of the files I need to process are stored locally, the code progresses through each of the request methods, finally getting to processAllThePages, which calls the method to end the chain and set the object originally allocated in the loop to nil. The next time through the loop we allocate a new object, initiate the chain, and  — as long as we don’t have to make a request through the network — again process all the files and call endFileFetchChain to set the custom object to nil so it can be releases. However, when we DO have to go to the network for a file request, the custom object is never released, even though the code does call endFileFetchChain where the object is set to nil.
My guess is that because the network requests are asynchronous, the code returns immediately to the main loop where a new CustomObject is allocated and another request chain is initiated. Even though I do eventually call endFileFetchChain on the first object (which I’ve verified by comparing object addresses), the reference count never goes to zero because the original reference created in the loop is still around.  Does that sound right? And if so, how might I go about restructuring the code to avoid the problem?
Oh! Also, when a custom object contains other custom objects, will those objects be released when the parent object is released, or so I need some sort of custom de-allocation routine on each of my custom objects?
Thanks!

Run the app within Xcode, trigger the leak, then click the Debug Memory Graph control found within the debugger controls. The output will take a moment to produce, when ready study it: select the leaking objects on the left, and study the produced graph. Usually that provides a smoking gun.

And to your last question: pay attention to circular references like A->B->C->A. These will not ever release unless you break them up.

Don't need check co.c1 for nil to assign nil to it. And you don't need to reset it is you nullify co

Thanks for the response and the memory graph was very helpful. As it turns out, the code above works fine and doesn't "technically" leak. However... the 'n' passed into the loop that drives the process is quite large; around 12,000. So that means that I was loading approximately 288,000 web pages of various sizes, along with a tone of custom objects being created and disposed of within this single loop. While nothing was leaking, the autorelease pool was HUGE!!! This eventually filled available memory until the application crashed.

I was able to fix the problem by inserting @autoreleasepool at a strategic point within the main loop. In my actual code, that one loop is really three loops, so I found a spot that was a good balance of performance and managing the memory.
